# How to override property of css class for individual dialog windows

Tags: css

I'm working in a component based framework that automatically styles a modal dialog window's header with a particular class called window-header.

I can adjust that class as I see fit in an external stylesheet:

```
.window-header {
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 10%;
    top: -2px!important;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 25px;
}
```

In this case, the header is being hidden, but utilized so the user can drag the dialog window around the screen. It's a click and drag area on the dialog window. For certain dialog windows, I need to change the width property of this draggable area.

I can dynamically add a css class to these certain window's div, such as `<div class="_12">`. And here is a simplified representation of the html:

```
<div class="_12">
  <div>
    <div class="window-header">
```

I have tried variations of the following in the same external css file (and it must be defined in the same external css):

```
._12 > .window-header {
   width: 95% !important;
}
```

Variations included using two '>' between ._12 and window-header, and moving the ._12 > window-header definition above the 'main' window-header definition.

However the width is not getting overridden.

The question - What is the solution? or is it even possible to override the width property of window-header for this specific situation?

EDIT - adjusted as suggested to `._12 > .window-header`

EDIT 2 - adding DevTools screenshot to show width not getting overridden

EDIT 3 - expanded view of DevTools screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are being too specific on your selector. You are also missing the class identifier on `window-header`. Needs to be `.window-header` Just use:

```
._12 .window-header
```

Alternatively, you could use this more verbose selector:

```
._12 > * > .window-header
```

If you're still having issues, check out the CSS in DevTools to see where it might be getting overridden. On this page, you can see the `min-width` property getting overridden and where it is happening.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing class identifier. I've tried both these suggestions, both before and after the main window-header class, but didn't work.

Comment: For sanity sake, try giving the properties the `!important` value and see if that works. `width: 95% !important;`

Comment: `!important` didn't help. Thanks though.

Comment: You should check out what is going on in DevTools. You should be able to see your properties being applied somewhere, then overridden by something else.

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking in DevTools - screenshot added to question

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what framework you're using I'd guess you just need a higher specificity score for the selector you want to override the other one.

If the selector in the stylesheet is just `.window-header` then it scores a 10 in specificity, if your markup is what you showed above then this would work `._12 div .window-header` since it would score 21 and have a higher level of specificity. You can learn more about how specificity is calculated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance#Specificity_2) and there's even a handy [calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/) for it.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details. ._12 div .window-header did not work, unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure that your markup is structured as `div._12>div>div.window-header` ? Can you expand the dev tools screenshot to include the `._12` element?

Comment: Expanded DevTools screenshot added. `._12` in this case is `._377_System_Maintenance`

Comment: I don't see the `._377_System_Maintenance` class being overridden in the styles pane, are you sure that the styles you are adding are being applied? Even if the stylesheet of the component is taking precedence over your styles they should be visible and crossed out in dev tools.

Comment: You're right - there was an issue with the dynamic addition of the individual window's class name that caused the final bit of headache. +1 for helping find the last problem I was having. I'm giving the answer to @Dan Mullin due to the class identifier and the `!important;` suggestions. Your `div` in between the class names also worked, but so does leaving the `div` out. But thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted? 1. You don't need to put a ">" sign. It is enough to write as I wrote in the example. 2. You forgot to put a full stop before `window-header`. This is a class.

```css
.window-header {
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 10%;
    top: -2px!important;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 25px;
    
    background-color: green;
}

._12 .window-header {
   width: 95%;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="_12">
  <div>
    <div class="window-header"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing that the overriding class should be below the main class.